# I am very new to python and trying out new tests and what is best method to create age bands for a range of data ina column

Tags: python

Within my "headcount" data set I have a column of data listing everyone's age in years
Column = Age_Yrs

I would like to create bands so that output totals numbers of individuals that fall within each band and provides out such as:
AGE    20-29 xx , 30-39 - xx , 40-49 - xx , 50-59- xx , 60-69 - xx

Comment: You mean you need to create a new column with `age_range` for each individuals..?and also provide some sample dataset and expected output

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what are you trying to do?

Do you want to loop through the ages of the people in the data, and for every person you want to increment the value of the relevant age band by 1?

For a 43y/o person you want to increase the value of the 40-49 band by 1, in order to count the number of people in the relevant age groups, right?

If that is the case, you might wanna loop through the age of every person in the list, for every age you want setdefault() a key in a dictionary and increment the value by 1...

You didn't write a lot about dataset, so I show you how you'd be able to do this with a list, you can modify this to fit your needs:

```
lst = [1, 2, 6, 10, 12, 18]
age_bands = {}

for age in lst:
 if 0<age<10:
  age_bands.setdefault('0-9', 0)
  age_bands['0-9'] += 1
 elif 10<=age<20:
  age_bands.setdefault('10-19', 0)
  age_bands['10-19'] += 1
  ...
  ...
print(age_bands)
{'0-9': 3, '10-19': 3}
```

Comment: Apologies first question written, I have 100 people and each of their ages want a simple way of counting how many individuals are in each banded age group . I would guess I have to create bands first then count >19 <30 to obtain 20-29 age group total

Comment: So the ages are probably in an excel spreadsheet?

You can transform them into a list with the pandas module then:  
`import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel('filename.xlsm', sheetname=0) # can also index sheet by 
name or fetch all sheets
mylist = df['column name'].tolist()`

After having them transformed into a list-dataset you could apply the code of my previous response..

Comment: Thank you very much , do you need the elif  line of code for each age group or just the two lines below it ?  sorry if silly question

Comment: Observe that `age//10` produces 0 for 0-9, 1 for 10-19, etc. So you can simply use this number as the dictionary key, and avoid a long and repetitive `if ... elif ... elif ... else` structure. Mapping the number to a human-readable range expression should be reasonably trivial as well (number * 10 through ((number + 1) * 10) - 1).